# Interactive iteration of a formula?

Tags: loops, iteration, formula

Firstly I apologise that this is a bit broad. If there is a better Stack Exchange board, please point me to it :)

I am looking for a way to iterate through a formula hundreds of times (or just constantly running) where a user can adjust a dataset and see the results (again, likely in real time?)

The idea being that I want to look at creating a formula for two players fighting in an RPG game. They will each have some stats, and I want to see what % win rate each has, based on a formula of my own devising.

I know PHP and Javascript, some Java and C# if that helps :)

I have started to tinker with a basic JS script, but I'd like to present a bar showing the % win/loss rates and again, have the interaction element if possible (rather then have to set the values, run it, read the results, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Look up Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: From what I can tell (and I may be totally wrong) Monte Carlo is about using random values to get a variety of results? There will be some randomness involved in my formula e.g pick a number in a certain range. Is that the kind of thing you mean? If so, yea sure, that's the plan. My question is about how to run this in a loop, where I can see some results real time (player vs player win rates) and be able to change say player 1's strength and see the results change due to that.

Comment: As it stands, your question is extremely broad. Once you've gotten some parts working, you can ask about the particulars of where you're stuck.

Comment: Yea I did say it was broad to begin with :) No way around that fact though. I'd like to hear suggestions on how others would maybe approach this, understanding that I know the programming languages mentioned.